# How to write function in Python to get row values as percent of grouped total values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe containing the following columns:

```
    Date    | Origin  | Destination | Service | Demand
    April 4 | Chicago | Toronto     | Ground  |250
    April 4 | Chicago | Tampa       | Ground  |250
    April 5 | Chicago | Orlando     | Air     |100
    April 5 | Chicago | Seattle     | Air     |400
```

I would like to write a function in Python or use a pandas function to get the demand column as a percent of total by 'Date' and 'Origin'

So if I have the following groupby:

```
  df.groupby(['Date','Origin'])['Demand'].sum().reset_index()
```

giving me the following:

```
         Date    | Origin  | Demand
         April 4 | Chicago | 500
         April 5 | Chicago | 500
```

My desired output is:

```
    Date    | Origin  | Destination | Service | Demand | Percentage
    April 4 | Chicago | Toronto     | Ground  |250     | 0.5
    April 4 | Chicago | Tampa       | Ground  |250     | 0.5
    April 5 | Chicago | Orlando     | Air     |100     | 0.2
    April 5 | Chicago | Seattle     | Air     |400     | 0.8
```

how would I go about writing something that would give me the percentage column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `transform`

```
df['Pct']=df['Demand']/df.groupby(['Date', 'Origin'])['Demand'].transform('sum')
```

Comment: @NazaninZinouri if that work for you , would you like accept it ?